# SQL Query Hibernate with clause where

Tags: java, hibernate

how should be this query in hibernate

```
public Double getValuPrice(int param1, int param2){

        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM TableClass WHERE e.product= :param1 and e.type = :param2");
        query.setParameter("param1 ",param1);
        query.setParameter("param2",param2);

        result = query.uniqueResult();
        List lista = query.list();

        return lista;
}
```

and i want show the value returned in a Servlet

```
List list = classDao.getValuPrice(origem, destino);

out.println("<h1>" + list.eq(0) + "</h1>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you are doing `from TableClass` and then `WHERE e.product = :param1`. I would have thought that would give you an error along the lines of `Unable to resolve path [e.product], unexpected token [e]`. Also you have a rogue space in one of your parameters, which will give you a `could not locate named parameter [param1 ]` error.

You don't, however, need the `select *` as suggested by Lenin's answer (see the [Hibernate manual (v4.3 §11.4.1 "Executing Queries")](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing))

So correcting these:

1. remove the space in `"param1 "`
2. specify a type for `result` (and do a cast) - unless `result` is a field you haven't shown in your sample code
3. and, of course, remove `e.` before your properties in the query (or add `e` as an alias for `TableClass`)
4. You are returning a `List` but the method specifies a `Double` - I'm not sure what you want to do here so you'll need to work that out yourself.

The code now looks like

```
public Double getValuPrice(int param1, int param2){
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM TableClass WHERE product= :param1 and type = :param2");
    query.setParameter("param1",param1);
    query.setParameter("param2",param2);
    // assuming result is a field with type TableClass    
    result = (TableClass)query.uniqueResult();
    List lista = query.list();

    return lista; // <-- fix the return statement
}
```

If you want to return a specific field on `TableClass`, which is a `Double` (e.g. `double price;`) then do:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select price from TableClass WHERE product= :param1 and type = :param2"
...
Double result = ((Number) q.uniqueResult()).doubleValue();
```

Comment: cool i teach new things with your answer, i already fix the wrongs and is working now ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing Select clause and table alias.
It should be like

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Select * FROM TableClass e WHERE e.product= :param1 and e.type = :param2");
```